# How to scrape all comments from a news site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape some contents of a [news-site](https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/article/1573772/%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B6%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%9F%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%80-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%99%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE-%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8C%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%A5%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%A2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F)
such as news description, tags, comments etc. Successfully done with the description and tags. But, while scraping the comments, the tags are not showing after finding by the tags by beautifulsoup, although it is showing if I inspect the page.

I just want to scrape all the comments (nested comments also) in the page and make them a single string to save in a csv file.

```
import requests
import bs4
from time import sleep
import os

url = 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/article/1573772/%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B6%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%9F%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%80-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%99%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE-%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8C%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%A5%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%A2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F'

resource = requests.get(url, timeout = 3.0)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resource.text, 'lxml')

# working as expected
tags = soup.find('div', {'class':'topic_list'})
tag = ''
tags = tags.findAll('a', {'':''})
for t in range(len(tags)):
    tag = tag + tags[t].text + '|'

# working as expected
content_tag = soup.find('div', {'itemprop':'articleBody'})
content_all = content_tag.findAll('p', {'':''})
content = ''
for c in range(len(content_all)):
    content = content + content_all[c].text

# comments not found
comment = soup.find('div', {'class':'comments_holder'})
print(comment)
```

console:

```
<div class="comments_holder">
<div class="comments_holder_inner">
<div class="comments_loader"> </div>
<ul class="comments_holder_ul latest">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see in Firefox/Developer tools is not what you received through `requests`. The comments are loading separately through AJAX and they are in JSON format.

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/article/1573772/%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B6%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%9F%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%80-%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%99%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE-%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8C%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%A5%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%A2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F'

comment_url = 'https://www.prothomalo.com/api/comments/get_comments_json/?content_id={}'
article_id = re.findall(r'article/(\d+)', url)[0]

comment_data = requests.get(comment_url.format(article_id)).json()

print(json.dumps(comment_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "5529951": {
        "comment_id": "5529951",
        "parent": "0",
        "label_depth": "0",
        "commenter_name": "MD Asif Iqbal",
        "commenter_image": "//profiles.prothomalo.com/profile/999009/picture/",
        "comment": "\u098f\u0987 \u09ad\u09be\u09b0 \u09ac\u09be\u0982\u09b2\u09be\u09a6\u09c7\u09b6\u0995\u09c7 \u09b8\u09be\u09b0\u09be\u099c\u09c0\u09ac\u09a8 \u09ac\u09b9\u09a8 \u0995\u09b0\u09a4\u09c7 \u09b9\u09ac\u09c7",
        "create_time": "2019-01-08 19:59",
        "comment_status": "published",
        "like_count": "\u09e6",
        "dislike_count": "\u09e6",
        "like_me": null,
        "dislike_me": null,
        "device": "phone",
        "content_id": "1573772"
    },
    "5529952": {
        "comment_id": "5529952",
        "parent": "0",

... and so on.
```

Comment: That long percent-encoded string seems to be just article title: `print(unquote('%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6% ... '))` prints: `বাংলাদেশি-পাসপোর্টধারী-রোহিঙ্গারা-সৌদি-থেকে-ঢাকায়`

Comment: @abdusco Yeah, it is. I couldn't force Firefox to copy/paste unicode URL to SublimeText. But anyway, it works.